# Does OpenFIGI have precanned files?

Tags: bloomberg

From what I understand, Bloomberg Open Symbology is now transitioning to OpenFigi:

http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/

> "BSYM.bloomberg.com will be *SHUT-OFF* on June 1st. It is being replaced by OpenFIGI.com."

You could download a precanned file from BSYM (from http://bdn-ak.bloomberg.com/precanned/...) however it seems that URL no longer has new files as of 6/9/2016.

Does OpenFIGI have a similar precanned file URL?  (I know they have an API but I'm interested in the precanned file.)

Comment: You would probably get a quicker response by asking them directly.